# Enterprise Library Console: no Logging Exception Handler

Tags: visual-studio, enterprise-library

I'm developing a new WPF project with C#, Visual Studio 2015 Community, .NET Framework 4.6.1 and Enterprise Library (latest version).

I'm trying to use Enterprise Library Console to add a Logging Exception Handler:

[image]

Do I have to do something to show Logging Exception handler option?

Here is my package.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.Common" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.Logging" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the NuGet package for [EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging/).  That package is what provides the connection between the Exception Handling Block and the Logging Block (it provides the ExceptionHandler that uses the Logging block).

Comment: Thanks, but now (before add the new NuGet package) on Configuration console only appears on Block menu: Add application settings and Add Configuration settings.

Comment: If Nuget's package folder isn't inside solution dir happens that I have explained before.

Comment: If the binaries are not in the expected NuGet package location then you can change the search path of `EnterpriseLibraryConfigurationToolBinariesPathV6` in the .sln file.  e.g.  GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
  EnterpriseLibraryConfigurationToolBinariesPathV6 = packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Common.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45;packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45
 EndGlobalSection

Comment: When the packages were in `D:\MyDevelopments\MySolution\External\Packages\ ` and the VS solution is in `D:\MyDevelopments\MySolution\ ` it works. But, when the packages are in `D:\MyDevelopments\External\Packages\ ` and the VS solution is in `D:\MyDevelopments\MySolution\ ` it doesn't work. On both cases the solution compiles. Thanks.